# Regex: Extract "Key: Value" (No Delimiter)

Tags: javascript, regex, string

#### Can you extract these *"key: value"* pairs with ONE regex only?

```
"a: xyz   b:  pqr st  c: lm no p"
```

The result I would like:

```
"a" => "xyz"
"b" => "pqr st"
"c" => "lm no p"
```

---

#### My Attempt (With <strike>Two</strike> Regex)

```
var s = 'a: xyz   b:  pqr st  c: lm no p';
var r = /(?:.(?!(?:a|b|c):))+/g;
var m;

while ((m = r.exec(s))) {

    var s2 = m[0];
    var r2 = /(a|b|c):\s*(.+)/;
    var m2 = r2.exec(s2);

    console.log('"' + m2[1] + '" => "' + m2[2] + '"');
}
```

The result I get:

```
"a" => "xyz  "
"b" => "pqr st "
"c" => "lm no p"
```

*So, can this be done with ONE regex only?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex pattern `/(\w+):\s*([^:]+)(?=\s|$)/g`

See **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qtsxN/)**.

To trim whitespace characters use around use regex pattern

```
/(\w+):\s*([^:]*\S)\s*(?=\w+:|$)/g
```

See **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BLVed/)**.

```
 /\b(\w+):\s*([^:]*\S)\b\s*(?=\w+:|$)/g
```

See **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bhNvp/)**.

Comment: Nope, doesn't get the "st" in b or the "no p" in c.

Comment: @GrantShield - Click on demo link again. Works for me!

Comment: @GrantShield - I have posted updated version that trim whitespace characters

Comment: Thanks, but if the key is longer than one char it doesn't work.

Comment: @GrantShield - Answer/Code has been updated based on your comment

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
var s = 'a: xyz   b:  pqr st  c: lm no p';
var r = /(?:\s|^)(\w+):\s*(.*?)(?=\s+\w+:|$)/g;
var m;

while ((m = r.exec(s))) {
    console.log('"' + m[1] + '" => "' + m[2] + '"');
}
```

Comment: Almost perfect, thank you! Anyway to trim the whitespace in the values?

Comment: `/(?:.(?!(?:a|b|c):))+\w/g`

The \w at the end will trim the whitespace.

Comment: This one allows multi char keys (which is great!) but there is white-space before some of the values. It it possible to trim that?

Comment: `/(?:\s|^)(\w+):\s*(.*?)(?=\s+\w+:|$)/g;`

Comment: Wrong! - I've posted correct code in the above comment 1 minute ago. Use that one!

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
/(?:.(?!(?:a|b|c):))+\w/g
```

Comment: This one doesn't seem to capture any groups.